Obstacle avoiding robot using telematics data - I don't know why my code is showing the error
I am trying to use the #include <WiFi.h>  but it is not working.
I am using the blynk.
I have also used the temperature which is needed in this project.
When I remove the <WiFi.h> then it shows an error in the <WiFiClient.h>.
When I remove the <WiFi.h> then it shows an error in the next line.
It is showing build fail! I don't know the reason
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>

#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID ""
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME ""
#define BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN ""


// #define BLYNK_PRINT Serial

char ssid[] = "Wokwi-GUEST";
char pass[] = "";

BlynkTimer timer;

int dirPin[] = {33, 13, 18, 16};
int stepPin[] = {32, 12, 19, 17}; 

#define pin_trig1 26
#define pin_echo1 27
#define pin_echo2 22
#define pin_trig2 23

long duration=0;
int distance=0;

const int stepsPerRevolution=300;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi");
  WiFi.begin("Wokwi-GUEST", "", 6);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(" Connected!");  

  Blynk.begin(BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN,ssid,pass );
  timer.setInterval(1000L,temperature);

  pinMode(pin_trig1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_echo1, INPUT);
  pinMode(pin_trig2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_echo2, INPUT);

  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    pinMode(dirPin[i], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(stepPin[i], OUTPUT);
    
  }
}

void forward()
{
  digitalWrite(dirPin[0],HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dirPin[1],LOW);
  digitalWrite(dirPin[2],HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dirPin[3],LOW);

  for(int i=0;i<stepsPerRevolution;i++)
  {
    for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
      digitalWrite(stepPin[x],HIGH);
    }
    delayMicroseconds(7000);
    for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
      digitalWrite(stepPin[x],LOW);
    }
    delayMicroseconds(7000);

  }
  Serial.println("Going forward");

}

void backward()
{
  digitalWrite(dirPin[0],LOW);
  digitalWrite(dirPin[1],HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dirPin[2],LOW);
  digitalWrite(dirPin[3],HIGH);

  for(int i=0;i<stepsPerRevolution;i++)
  {
    for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
      digitalWrite(stepPin[x],HIGH);
    }
    delayMicroseconds(7000);
    for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
      digitalWrite(stepPin[x],LOW);
    }
    delayMicroseconds(7000);

  }
  Serial.println("Going backward");
}


int total_distance(int trigPin, int echoPin)
{
  digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);

  duration=pulseIn(echoPin,HIGH);
  distance=duration*(0.034/2);
  return distance;

}


//!!! There is no use of the temperature in this project !!!  It was just for experimenting

void temperature()
{
  int analogValue=analogRead(21);
  float celsius= (analogValue ) / 10.24;
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(celsius);
  Serial.println(" in celsius!!");
  delay(1000);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V1,celsius);
}

void loop()
{
  int forward_distance=total_distance(pin_trig1,pin_echo1);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V0,forward_distance);
  Serial.print("forward_distance: ");
  Serial.print(forward_distance);

  if(forward_distance<100)
  {
    Blynk.logEvent("obstacles_detected","Obstacles are detected !! Take action!!");
    backward();
  }
  else
  {
    int backward_distance=total_distance(pin_trig2,pin_echo2);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V0,forward_distance);
    Serial.print("backward_distance: ");
    Serial.print(backward_distance);

    if(backward_distance<100)
    {
      forward();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("NO OBSTACLES DETECTED!!!");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  temperature();
  Serial.println("-_-_-_-_-_-_");
  Blynk.run();
  timer.run();
  

}



Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run the code to reproduce your issue.

move #include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h> after the defines so it can see them
